# Flex-fill parent with multiple h-100 children with Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am  currently using Bootstrap 4.1.3 for a project.

I have managed to create multiple children with `h-100` within a `flex-fill`with the help of `<div class="h-100">` wrapper.

Although it works as intended in Google Chrome, but it feels like I am doing something horribly wrong because when it comes to the smaller screens, these children elements expand more than 100% height of their parent.

Is there any better approach in CSS or Bootstrap 4 to achieve multiple child elements with 100% height inside a flex-fill parent that while retaining the responsiveness of Bootstrap 4?

Here is my [code pen demo](https://codepen.io/DarkyWuiChin/full/bQrKBY) for it.

Here is my sample code:

```css
html,body {
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Added Flex -->
  <div class="d-md-flex flex-column h-100">
    <!--p>Nav Bar</p-->
    <!-- Show selection when screen is in medium range-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar" aria-controls="mainNavBar"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Section 1</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100">
      <div class="row flex-fill">
        <!--Main Content-->
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="row h-100">
            <div id="mainSection" class="col-md-12 d-flex flex-column flex-fill">
              <div class="h-100"><!-- <<<Mentioned Wrapper -->
                <div id="section1" class="h-100 bg-warning">
                  <!--Sample Text-->
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos ne doming equidem persequeris, vis nostro detracto oportere ne, no
                    sit
                    menandri inciderint. Per tacimates salutatus voluptaria ex. An dolor munere sea. Nam et brute
                    noluisse, per
                    modus harum nominati no.
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div id="section2" class="h-100 bg-success">
                  <!--Sample Text-->
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos ne doming equidem persequeris, vis nostro detracto oportere ne, no
                    sit
                    menandri inciderint. Per tacimates salutatus voluptaria ex. An dolor munere sea. Nam et brute
                    noluisse, per
                    modus harum nominati no.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Profile Bar-->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="h-100 position-fixed" style="border:1px solid yellowgreen;">
            <p>Hi I am Darky</p>
            <p>
              Introduction 1:

              Hinc omittam inciderint eu duo, nisl doctus no duo, oratio quidam concludaturque cu vix. Te sea
              voluptatibus delicatissimi, nec ex habeo alienum efficiendi, id quis ludus detracto sit. Has ei libris
              patrioque, habeo corpora blandit id qui. Solum alterum blandit an quo. Vel modus novum nominavi eu, sit
              partem electram ea. Sit vero temporibus ne, sea cu justo dicit accusam.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

- Updated Question 18/11/2018

So my question is:

1. I don't understand why the mentioned wrapper `<div class="h-100">` is able to help `section1` and `section2` to be 100% height of 'mainSection' each.
2. Am I using the mentioned wrapper `<div class="h-100">` and flexbox correctly?

Comment: I checked your codepen and I can't replicate what you mean. i.e. I can't identify the problem. Everything seems to scale appropriately. Could you be a bit more descriptive of the problem and your desired results?

Comment: Using `height: 100%` (`h-100`) with Flexbox can be counter productive, as Flexbox has built-in features how children can fill their parents height. Flex columns and `flex: 1` will do that, and flex rows and its `align-items`, which default to `stretch`, has a similar effect. When it comes to your question, please try to narrow it down with a [mcve] to enable a more specific answer.